# Problem importing a module in django v4.1.7, pydroid3 python v3.9.7

Tags: python-3.x, django, pydroid

My urls.py and views.py files are in the same directory (my_app), after importing the views.py file from my urls.py file, whenever I try to start the development server I get a `module import error: no module named views` but when I compile and run the urls.py file I get an `import error: attempted relative import with no parent package`.

This is the code from urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

path('', index, name='index')

]
```

I tried modifying the import statement for views into:
`from views import index` and that removed the compilation error but not the server error.

Comment: try with the full path of views, something like : from project.my_app import views

Comment: I tried @weAreStarsDust suggestion and it worked successfully, thank you for the input

Answer (score 1):

`from .views import index` should fix problem

```py
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index')
]
```